# Many To Many Complex Polymorphic Relationship in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, laravel-5, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I'm doing the notification system in my project. I have a database in which I have users and clients who belong to users. Notifications can be added for both users and clients. That's why I used the Many to Many Polymorphic relationship, which works well up to a point. I can not deal with building relationships for the user, which will be take notifications both for him and for all of its customers.

User model:

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Client');
}

public function notifications()
{
  return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Notification', 'notifiable')
        ->withPivot('notice_time', 'user_seen')->withTimestamps();
  //Normally I would use it but here I will not catch notifications for clients
  return \Notification::whereHas('clients', function($q){
      $q->where('clients.user_id', $this->id);
    })->orWhereHas('users', function($q){
       $q->where('users.id', $this->id);
    });
  //The closest I have been using such code, however in this option I can't use wherePivot()
}
```

Notification model:

```
public function clients(){
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Client', $this->pivot)
        ->withPivot(self::USER_NOTICE_COLUMN, self::USER_SEEN_COLUMN)->withTimestamps();
}

public function users(){
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\User', $this->pivot)
        ->withPivot(self::USER_NOTICE_COLUMN, self::USER_SEEN_COLUMN)->withTimestamps();
}
```

Small preview of tables:

```
Notifiables     |Notifications | Clients | Users  |
----------------+--------------+---------+--------+
id              |id            |id       |id      |
notification_id |title         |user_id  |email   |
notifiable_id   |message       |name     |password|
user_seen       |              |surname  |        |
notice_time     |              |         |        |
notifiable_type |              |         |        |
```

Is there any possibility to build a relationship like this so that I can use  the user notifications function for user object and still being aple to use the query scopes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can't easily define such a relationship. The easiest way to start from Notification and join Pivot table.

```
public function notifications(){
    return \Notification::
    whereHas('clients', function($q){
        $q->where('clients.user_id', $this->id);
    })->orWhereHas('users', function($q){
        $q->where('users.id', $this->id);
    })->join('notifiables', 'notifications.id', '=', 'notifiables.notification_id');
}
```